# perl Kafka::Producer, "Kafka::Exception::Producer", "code", -1000, "message", "Invalid argument

Tags: perl, apache-kafka

I wrote kafka producer using kafka perl api, But i am getting error when i am passing variable for sending message while if i am hardcoding the message data it's not giving any error.

Perl program, where i added kafka producer code:

```
try {
    $kafka_connection = Kafka::Connection->new( host => $hadoop_server, port => '6667' );
    $producer = Kafka::Producer->new( Connection => $kafka_connection );
    my $topic = 'test1';
    my $partition = 0;
    my $message = $hadoop_str;
    my $response = $producer->send(
        $topic,             # topic
        $partition,                  # partition
        #"56b4b2b23c24c3608376d1ea,/obj/i386/ui/lib/access/daemon_map.So.gcda,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"         # message
        $hadoop_str
        #"t1,f9,1,1,1"
    );
} catch {
    my $error = $_;
    if ( blessed( $error ) && $error->isa( 'Kafka::Exception' ) ) {
        warn 'Error: (', $error->code, ') ',  $error->message, "\n";
        exit;
    } else {
        die $error;
    }
};
#                CCLib::run_system_cmd( $cmd );
}
```

Error Log:

```
-bash-3.2$ ./stream_binary_hadoop.pl
print (...) interpreted as function at ./stream_binary_hadoop.pl line 429.
<UNKNOWN> <UNKNOWN> Invalid argument: message = 56b4b2b23c24c3608376d1ea,/obj/i386/junos/usr.sbin/lmpd/lmpd_repl_msg_idr.gcda,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 at /opt/adp/projects/code_coverage/perl//5.10/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/Exception/Class/Base.pm line 85.
Exception::Class::Base::throw("Kafka::Exception::Producer", "code", -1000, "message", "Invalid argument: message = 56b4b2b23c24c3608376d1ea,/obj/i38"...) called at /opt/adp/projects/code_coverage/perl//5.10/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/Kafka/Producer.pm line 374
Kafka::Producer::_error(Kafka::Producer=HASH(0x36955f8), -1000, "message = 56b4b2b23c24c3608376d1ea,/obj/i386/junos/usr.sbin/l"...) called at /opt/adp/projects/code_coverage/perl//5.10/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/Kafka/Producer.pm line 331
Kafka::Producer::send(Kafka::Producer=HASH(0x36955f8), "test1", 0, "56b4b2b23c24c3608376d1ea,/obj/i386/junos/usr.sbin/lmpd/lmpd_r"...) called at ./stream_binary_hadoop.pl line 175
main::try {...} () called at /opt/adp/projects/code_coverage/perl//5.10/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/Try/Tiny.pm line 81
eval {...} called at /opt/adp/projects/code_coverage/perl//5.10/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/Try/Tiny.pm line 72
Try::Tiny::try(CODE(0x3692888), Try::Tiny::Catch=REF(0x3692c78)) called at ./stream_binary_hadoop.pl line 190
main::stream(HASH(0x3692708)) called at ./stream_binary_hadoop.pl line 354
main::file_split(HASH(0x36927b0)) called at ./stream_binary_hadoop.pl line 413

at ./stream_binary_hadoop.pl line 188.
   main::catch {...} ("<UNKNOWN> Invalid argument: message = 56b4b2b23c24c3608376d1e"...) called at /opt/adp/projects/code_coverage/perl//5.10/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/Try/Tiny.pm line 104
   Try::Tiny::try(CODE(0x3692888), Try::Tiny::Catch=REF(0x3692c78)) called at ./stream_binary_hadoop.pl line 190
   main::stream(HASH(0x3692708)) called at ./stream_binary_hadoop.pl line 354
   main::file_split(HASH(0x36927b0)) called at ./stream_binary_hadoop.pl line 413
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve by wrapping my string with utf8::downgrade. Somehow it was taking my string as utf-8, and kafka producer, had check for need non utf-8 string.

My working code:

```
 my $arcs_val = join( ',', @arc_a );
        my $hadoop_str = $testid . ',' . $gcda_file_name . ',' . $arcs_val;
        utf8::downgrade($hadoop_str);
         try {
                my $topic = $inputs[0];
                my $partition = $inputs[1];
                my $response = $producer->send(
                    $topic,                      # topic
                    $partition,                  # partition
                    $hadoop_str
               );
```